Any good and easy to use .docx template for Academic CV?
So I have all the sections and contents  ready but still lack a good professional looking template (.docx). There are many "CV builder" sites but some aren't free others don't produce good results.  Does anyone know of a good template especially for PhD applications?

https://github.com/hongtaoh/cv_emulate -- A Good place to get some inspiration.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rK2prBm6ga4EGdlbNZ66NS0_KBLrOCSf/edit - This one is from Harvard.
Most universities have a docx template. Just Search on Google "Academic CV docx template from XYZ".
On the off chance you are okay with using LaTeX - simply go to Overleaf (completely free) and search there.
